# How to write a regular expression for to capture letters, numbers, special characters and international characters

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to write a regular expression that captures uppercase, lowercase letters and numbers, special characters and finally international characters. By international characters I mean things like: ¿ â ê î ô û Â Ê Î Ô Û.

I'm 90% done, this is my expression, it covers, uppercase, lowercase, letters,numbers and special characters, Im struggling with incorporating the regex for international characters to my current regular expression, please see below my expression:

Uppercase, lowercase, letters, numbers and special characters:

```
^[|a-zA-Z0-9 ¬`!"£$%^&*()_+={[}:;@'~#<,>.?/|]{0,3}$
```

Regex for international characters:

```
[^\p{L}0-9]{0,3}$
```

I want to ensure that the length of the international character is limited to a length of 3.

Please help!

Comment: Three in a row, or in total?

Comment: @Grantly In total. So one expression that covers it all. I've already written the first expression that covers letters, numbers and special characters. I've also written the one for international characters, im just trying to combine them rather than have two separate expressions

Comment: Is that by any chance a password rule? If yes why restrict security?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^([|a-zA-Z0-9 ¬`!"£$%^&*()_+={[}:;@'~#<,>.?/|]|[^\p{L}0-9]){0,3}$
```